# alphabetizing a list from a single string

Tags: java, string, sorting, alphabetical

I'm trying to create a program that takes in a single string and sorts the words by alphabetical order, this is what i have at the moment but nothing is printing out:

```
System.out.println("Enter words, sepaated by commas and spaces");
      String input= scanner.next();
      String[] words= input.split(" ");
      Arrays.sort(words);
      StringBuilder zoop= new StringBuilder();
      for(int i=1; i<words.length; i++){
       zoop.append(" ");
       zoop.append(words[i]);
      }
      String sorted= zoop.toString();
      System.out.println(sorted);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

and

```
for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
```

[scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) only returns the next complete token. In your case, it returns just the first word. Since the for loop started with 1 instead of 0, the program printed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors that cooperate to produce no output. First, look at the difference between [Scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) and [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29). Then realize that [arrays are 0-based in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and take a second look at your [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i=1; i<words.length; i++){`

should be

`for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){`

Comment: That is a problem, but not the REAL problem